# Immutable returns undefined with jestjs

Tags: jestjs, immutable.js

I just made a simple test:
`npm i babel-cli babel-jest immutable jest-cli babel-preset-2015`
And having simple test:

```
import {List} from 'immutable'

describe('it works',()=>{
  it('should just work',()=>{
    let li = List.of(1,3)
    expect(li.size).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

Very simple but test gives this:

`- TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`

While `List` is defined and it is Function.

Do you have an Idea why this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to add `jest.unmock('immutable')` on the first line.

According to docs:

> By default, Jest automatically makes all calls to require() **return a mocked version** of the real module – so we need to tell Jest not to mock the file we want to test or else require('../fetchCurrentUser') will return a mock.